# Appcelerator: How Can I Change the Orange Border for Active TextFields for Android?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

In Appcelerator, whenever I have a TextField, the border is always a thick orange. How can I style this? backgroundSelectedColor seems to have no effect and backgroundColor changes the actual background color. I want the background color to stay the same but the border color to change. How is this possible? Is it? Who wants a thick orange border?!? How is that the default?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to achieve the same effect which you can see below by using `backgroundFocusedImage` and `backgroundImage` properties with no luck.

[image]
[image]

Finally I end up implementing eventListeners swapping those properties manually (*note: I'm using Alloy, so if you are using only Titanium your code can look slightly different*):

```
function toggleFocusBackground(event) {

  function swap(obj, prop1, prop2) {
    var tmp;
    tmp = obj[prop1];
    obj[prop1] = obj[prop2];
    obj[prop2] = tmp;
  }

  function multiSwap(obj, props) {
    var prop1, prop2;
    for (prop1 in props) {
      prop2 = props[prop1];
      if (typeof obj[prop1] !== 'undefined' && typeof obj[prop2] !== 'undefined') {
        swap(obj, prop1, prop2);
      }
    }
  }

  var node, i;
  var props = {
    'backgroundFocusedImage': 'backgroundImage',
    'focusedColor': 'color'
  };

  for (i in this.parent.children) {
    multiSwap( this.parent.children[i], props );
  }
}

for (var i in $) {
  if (typeof $[i].value !== 'undefined') {
    $[i].addEventListener('focus', toggleFocusBackground);
    $[i].addEventListener('blur', toggleFocusBackground);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reference anywhere in any documentation or any Google search of the "focusedColor" property.

Comment: focusedColor is just my custom property.
When user focus in TextField (I'm checking if object is TextField by testing if it has value property) I switch values of two pairs of properties:
backgroundImage gets value backgrounfFocusedImage
color gets value from focusedColor
When blur event is catched values are reversed and TextField is back in normal state.